# don't know how to open the next-auth signIn in new window

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Hey folks I have imported `signIN()` from the

```
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
```

and I'm using it like this

```
<Button onClick={() => signIn('discord')}>Login</Button>
```

but the problem with this setup is that the authentication link opens up in the same tab which I don't want I want it to open up in the new window and when the authentication is done the new window automatically close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/pages/index.js:`

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import NewWindow from 'react-new-window'
import { signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

const HomePage = () => {
  const [popup, setPopUp] = useState(false)
  const [session, loading] = useSession()

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <p>loading session...</p>
      ) : session ? (
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Logout</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => setPopUp(true)}>Login</button>
      )}

      {popup && !session ? (
        <NewWindow url="/sign-in" onUnload={() => setPopUp(false)} />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

`src/pages/sign-in.js:`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

const SignInPage = () => {
  const [session, loading] = useSession()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !session) void signIn('google')
    if (!loading && session) window.close()
  }, [session, loading])

  return null
}

export default SignInPage
```

From: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/178#issuecomment-757513968

Comment: is there any other way for doing same thing without using `react-new-window` library because I do not want to make sperate signIn.js  file

Comment: I'm one year late here but might give it a shot - any idea why react-new-window doesn't support react 17 but supports 16 and 18?